# Сохранить несколько вариантов из динамического добавленного chekedlistbox с#

Tags: c#, winforms

Создаю динамически tablelayout с различными элементами. Далее циклом пробегаюсь по всем control, чтобы собрать введённую информацию. Есть один chekedlistbox, где надо выбрать несколько вариантов... Пытаясь обратиться через Control(внизу кода) он ругается, что нет метода ChekedItems, как быть?

```
 foreach (Control tb9 in c.Controls)
                {
                    if (tb9 is Panel)
                    {
                        foreach (Control text in tb9.Controls)
                        {
                            if (text is TextBox)
                            {
                                switch (number)
                                {
                                    case 0:
                                        antifraud.sourceId = text.Text;
                                        number++;
                                        break;
                                    case 1:
                                        payerIdentifier.hash = text.Text;
                                        number++;
                                        break;
                                    case 2:
                                        payer.bik = text.Text;
                                        number++;
                                        break;
                                    case 3:
                                        payer.inn = text.Text;
                                        number++;
                                        break;
                                    case 4:
                                        payer.payerName = text.Text;
                                        number++;
                                        break;
                                    case 5:
                                        paymentCard.number = text.Text;
                                        number++;
                                        break;
                                    case 6:
                                        paymentCard.sum = text.Text;
                                        number++;
                                        break;
                                    case 7:
                                        paymentCard.currency = text.Text;
                                        number++;
                                        break;
                                    case 8:
                                        paymentCard.dateTimeAt = text.Text;
                                        number++;
                                        break;
                                    case 9:
                                        paymentCard.rrn = text.Text;
                                        number++;
                                        break;
                                    case 10:
                                        settlement.number = text.Text;
                                        number++;
                                        break;
                                    case 11:
                                        settlement.sum = text.Text;
                                        number++;
                                        break;
                                    case 12:
                                        settlement.currency = text.Text;
                                        number++;
                                        break;
                                    case 13:
                                        settlement.dateTimeAt = text.Text;
                                        number++;
                                        break;
                                    case 14:
                                        phoneNumber.number = text.Text;
                                        number++;
                                        break;
                                    case 15:
                                        phoneNumber.sum = text.Text;
                                        number++;
                                        break;
                                    case 16:
                                        phoneNumber.currency = text.Text;
                                        number++;
                                        break;
                                    case 17:
                                        phoneNumber.dateTimeAt = text.Text;
                                        number++;
                                        break;
                                    case 18:
                                        idNumber.number = text.Text;
                                        number++;
                                        break;
                                    case 19:
                                        idNumber.sum = text.Text;
                                        number++;
                                        break;
                                    case 20:
                                        idNumber.currency = text.Text;
                                        number++;
                                        break;
                                    case 21:
                                        idNumber.dateTimeAt = text.Text;
                                        number++;
                                        break;
                                    case 22:
                                        device.ip = text.Text;
                                        number++;
                                        break;
                                    case 23:
                                        device.imsi = text.Text;
                                        number++;
                                        break;
                                    case 24:
                                        device.imei = text.Text;
                                        number++;
                                        break;
                                    case 25:
                                        device.aiic = text.Text;
                                        number++;
                                        break;
                                    case 26:
                                        device.cati = text.Text;
                                        number++;
                                        break;
                                    case 27:
                                        device.caic = text.Text;
                                        number++;
                                        break;
                                    case 28:
                                        payee.bik = text.Text;
                                        number++;
                                        break;
                                    case 29:
                                        payee.inn = text.Text;
                                        number++;
                                        break;
                                    case 30:
                                        payee.payeeName = text.Text;
                                        number++;
                                        break;
                                    case 31:
                                        pаymentCard.number = text.Text;
                                        number++;
                                        break;
                                    case 32:
                                        sеttlement.number = text.Text;
                                        number++;
                                        break; 
                                    case 33:
                                        phоneNumber.number = text.Text;
                                        number++;
                                        break;
                                    case 34:
                                        idNumbеr.number = text.Text;
                                        number++;
                                        break;
                                    case 35:
                                        additionalStatus.crossBorder = text.Text;
                                        number++;
                                        break;
                                }
                            }
                            if (text is cCheckedListBox)
                            {
                                switch (podnumber)
                                {
                                    case 0:
                                        antifraud.victim = text.Text;
                                        podnumber++;
                                        break;
                                    case 1:
                                        payerTransferId.transferType = text.Text;
                                        podnumber++;
                                        break;
                                    case 2:
                                        payeeTransferId.transferType = text.Text;
                                        podnumber++;
                                        break;
                                }
                            }
                            if (text is CheckedListBox)
                            {
                                foreach (string test in text.CheckedItems)

                               additionalStatus.additionalTransactionApprove.Add(test);

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
           }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эта строка: `if (text is CheckedListBox)` проверяет, что переменная является нужным типом. Но переменная не меняет свой тип, а остаётся `Control`.

Нужно выполнить приведение типа (каст):

```
foreach (string test in ((CheckedListBox)text).CheckedItems)
```

Однако, и операция `is`, и приведение типа являются дорогими операциями.
Можно заменить их следующим кодом:

```
var checkedListBox = text as CheckedListBox;
if (checkedListBox != null)
{
    foreach (string test in checkedListBox.CheckedItems)
        additionalStatus.additionalTransactionApprove.Add(test);
}
```

Операция `as` тоже дорогая, зато сравнение с нулём очень дёшево. Считается, что в сумме это выгоднее. Но это мелочь, можно не заморачиваться.

---

Тип `Control` имеет свойство `Text`, поэтому код в других ветках `if` работает без каста.

Также в этих ветках нет нужды в `as`, т. к. приведение не нужно.

---

Немного критики.

Что это за имя: `tb9`? Дайте переменной нормальное название. `text`, на мой взгляд, тоже неудачное название. Я бы их назвал `outerControl` и `innerControl`. Переменную `test` я бы назвал `item` или `checkedItem`. Но я не авторитет, не надо на меня равняться.

Код в текущем виде слишком сложно читать, он не умещается на один экран монитора. Я бы разбил его на методы: например, можно вынести код внутри каждой ветки `if` в отдельный метод.

---

Начиная с версии C# 7.0 появился [паттерн матчинг](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is#pattern-matching-with-is) (сопоставление с образцом).

Если вы можете использовать новые версии языка, то код упрощается до следующего:

```
if (text is CheckedListBox checkedListBox)
{
    foreach (string test in checkedListBox.CheckedItems)
        additionalStatus.additionalTransactionApprove.Add(test);
}
```

Тут в одном операторе выполняется проверка типа и определение переменной.

Comment: Можно пример, как разбить на методы? Я о чем-то похожем думал, но с c# работаю меньше месяца и не знаю как это все оформить... Буду очень благодарен

Comment: @PavelKutsubin - лучше задать отдельный вопрос по рефакторингу, с меткой `инспекция-кода`.

Comment: а можно с вами пойти в чат ? Просто код вы уже видели и будет проще, как мне кажется